# Prove that $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ induce the same topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Suppose $d_{1}(x,y) = |x-y|$, $d_{2}(x, y) = |\phi(x) - \phi(y)|$, where $\phi(x) = \frac{x}{1 + |x|}$. Prove that $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ are metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ which induce the same topology.

It's easy to prove that $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ are metrics. Call the topologies induced by them $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$. I can prove that $\tau_{1}$ is finer than $\tau_{2}$, but I can't prove the inverse. Can any body please help me. Thanks

Comment: Consider the map $$\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1);\quad \phi(x) = \frac{x}{1+\lvert x\rvert}.$$ Show it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I can prove your map is a homeomorphism, and $d_{2}(x,y) = d(\phi(x), \phi(y))$, but then why $\tau_{2}$ is finer than $\tau_{1}$???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down like this:

1. Given a metric space $(Y,d)$, a set $X$, and a bijection $f\colon X \to Y$, the pull-back of $d$ via $f$, $f^\ast d \colon X\times X \to [0,\infty);\; f^\ast d(a,b) = d(f(a),f(b))$ is a metric on $X$. Thus $f\colon (X,f^\ast d) \to (Y,d)$ is an isometry, in particular a homeomorphism.
2. If, in the situation above, $X$ carries a prior topology $\tau$, we have two topologies on $X$, the original $\tau$, and the one induced by the pull-back of $d$, let's call it $\tau_{f^\ast d}$. We have $\tau = \tau_{f^\ast d}$ if and only if $\operatorname{id} \colon (X,\tau) \to (X,\tau_{f^\ast d})$ is a homeomorphism. Since the composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, and we know that $f \colon (X,\tau_{f^\ast d}) \to (Y,d)$ is a homeomorphism, that is the case if and only if $f\circ \operatorname{id} \colon (X,\tau) \to (Y,d)$ is a homeomorphism.

It remains to identify $X$, $Y$, $f$, $d$, $\tau$, $\tau_{f^\ast d}$.

Comment: perfect. Thanks so much Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can show that if $d_1(x_n,x)\to 0\iff d_2(x_n,x)\to 0$. It is more easy sometimes to use convergence,besides topology was invented for convergence. To give you a hint i'll show the more easy part ($\implies$).

Let $d_1(x_n,x)=|x_n-x|\to 0;$ then \begin{align}d_2(x_n,x)&=\frac {x_n}{1+|x_n|}-\frac {x}{1+|x|}\\&=\frac {(x_n-x)+(|x|x_n-|x_n|x)}{(1+|x_n|)(1+|x|)}.\end{align} We have that $|x_n-x|\to 0$ and $x_n\to x\implies |x_n|\to |x|$ and thus $d_2(x_n,x)\to 0.$

Comment: Can you explain why if $d_{1}(x_{n}, x) \rightarrow 0 <=> d_{2}(x_{n}, x) \rightarrow 0$, then 2 topologies are the same. This statement seems quite helpful in many case? Thanks

Comment: Yes $d1(x_n,x)→0<=>d2(x_n,x)→0$ which means that they produce the same open sets. to prove this,is not difficult but you need to write down some things( i cannot think any faster way),but think of it that they produce the same structure (this is algebraic term). Or each open set can be described equivalenlty by these two metrics.

Comment: I don't think it's right Dimitris. With your condition, I think we can only state that 2 topologies have the same Cauchy sequence, so if one is complete, then the other is complete, too. But how can they be the same?

Comment: No,it's quite right my friend:). Use it in these problems and you will remember me:)